# Free Form Fillable Forms: Bug in Schedule 3 with form 8863?

Tags: united-states, irs, free-file-fillable-forms

I'm trying to file my 2018 taxes, which include form 8863 (nonrefundable education credits) and therefore also schedule 3. I keep getting the following error when I file:

> Issue      : Business Rule IND-422 - Form 1040, Schedule 3, 'EducationCreditAmt' must be equal to Form 8863, 'NonrefundableEducationCrAmt'.
>
> The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
>   Field/Xpath: /efile:Return/efile:ReturnData/efile:IRS8863/efile:NonrefundableEducationCrGroup/efile:NonrefundableEducationCrAmt
>
> Issue      : Business Rule F1040-064-03 - Form 1040, 'TotalCreditsAmt' must be equal to the sum of the following: 'CTCODCAmt' and Form 1040, Schedule 3, 'ForeignTaxCreditAmt' and 'CreditForChildAndDepdCareAmt' and 'EducationCreditAmt' and 'RtrSavingsContributionsCrAmt' and 'ResidentialEnergyCreditAmt' and 'OtherCreditsAmt'.
>
> The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
>   Field/Xpath: /efile:Return/efile:ReturnData/efile:IRS1040/efile:TotalCreditsAmt

From these two errors, I would guess that "EducationCreditAmt" on schedule 3 isn't being set correctly on the software, despite it showing up correctly on the screen. However, all fields on schedule 3 are automatically calculated by free file, so I don't think there is much I can do about this.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and solved the problem? As a last resort I could just mail in my taxes, but hopefully there's an alternative.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have attempted to fix this five times.

Comment: I get the same error related to "retirement savings contribution credit." Only one value entered. That value equals the total. Yet the error says they're not equal. Seems like a s/w defect to me.

Comment: I just noticed this is listed as a bug in this page: https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/free-file-fillable-forms-help##knownsoftware
It's claimed it should be fixed by February 1.

Comment: @user121664 Good find.  Feel free to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is confirmed as a bug in https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/free-file-fillable-forms-help##knownsoftware with tentative fix date of February 1.

Edit: as of February 4, this bug seems to be fixed.

Edit: as of February 15, 2020, this bug is back and unfixed in the 2019 tax year software.